# Django date localization doesn't seem to work when run from command-line manage command

Tags: django, command-line, localization

I have a template which uses `{{date|date:"l j F"}}` to localize a date. When I use it in a view this works fine (served from either `./manage.py runserver` or uwsgi.

When I use this template to send an email from the command line using a management/commands command however, it falls back to the en_US locale. (Friday instead of Vrijdag etc)

I've included `settings.LANGUAGE_CODE`, `settings.USE_L10N` and `settings.USE_I18N` in the template to make sure which locale is being used, and then it says nl_NL in both cases, as expected.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 6):

It turns out one has to manually activate translation in management commands:

```
from django.utils import translation

translation.activate(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
```

did the trick. See https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10078